# Python selenium Open the link instead of download it

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, selenium-webdriver, url

I have an automation project that requires opening the URL to a Microsoft SharePoint file and performing some action on the website instead of downloading it.

In my excel, if i "click" the hyperlink I can get directly opened up in the browser using the always open file option in chrome.

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

#url that generated from my Excel file containing hyperlink
df = pd.DataFrame(['https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/Test.xlsx', 'https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/Test2.xlsx'])
df.columns = ['url']

options = Options()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = options)
for url in df.url:
    driver.get(url)
```

it just downloads the file instead of opening it in the browser if i code it using Selenium to open these url link

Answer (score 0):

At least in Chrome you should be able to prevent the save file dialog from opening and to specify a download directory.

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {
   'download.default_directory': '/tmp',
   'download. prompt_for_download': False,
}

options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

Comment: Tried many methods and had no luck. I have to reroute my automation flow directly and copy the full link to the website instead of generating it to Excel hyperlink.  Thanks anyway!